# Buffering a line

Tags: arcpy, buffer

I would like to construct a feature class consisting of every polygon in the landuse shapefile entirely within a 300 Feet buffer of the Road. But I always get error of C:\Road300 does not exist or not supported, even I see an out buffered road in the desired directory.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

Road='Road.shp'.
Landuse='Landuse.shp'
Road_Buffer=r'C:\Road300'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Road, 'Road_lyr') # Making layer arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Landuse, 'Landuse_lyr') # Making layer 
# Make buffer with 300 feet.
arcpy.Buffer_analysis('Road_lyr', Road_Buffer, '300 Feet', 'FULL')
# Selecting features by location
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('Landuse_lyr', 'COMPLETELY_WITHIN', Road_Buffer)
arcpy.CopyFeature_management('Landuse_lyr', Landuse)
```

Comment: it should be Road_Buffer=r'C:\Road300\\*something*.shp', you're pointing the buffer to a directory not a shapefile.

Comment: Even If I write Road_Buffer, I get this error message: Dataset C:\ Road300 does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation). Also could you please edit the script after it says: Making layer. The arcpy is another line in the script.

Comment: Assuming that the folder C:\Road300 exists and you have write access you need to provide a *feature class name* to export the buffer to. If you're exporting to a geodatabase you don't use an extension but if you're not you need to supply a valid file name and extension for the buffer output feature class.

Comment: If you don't need to show the buffer in a map and just need it to do the selection, you can write it to a temporary file in memory: `Road_Buffer=r'in_memory/buffer300'`. Then you won't clutter up your hard drive with intermediate files. It's also faster to skip writing and reading to your disk.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, above, you weren't creating a valid output datatype. If you're not outputting to a geodatabase, you need to provide a file extension. In my example, I've added ".shp" to the Road300 file.

Also, there is no reason to make a layer of the Road shapefile. Below, I make a layer of the buffered road (I think the subsequent select by location might work if you just pass the shapefile directly, but I'm not sure).

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

Road='Road.shp' # You had a period at the end of this line, which should have yielded an error
Landuse='Landuse.shp'
Road_Buffer=r'C:\Road300.shp'
# Making layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Landuse, 'Landuse_lyr') # Making layer
# Make buffer with 300 feet.
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(Road, Road_Buffer, '300 Feet', 'FULL')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Road_Buffer, 'Road_lyr')
# Selecting features by location
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('Landuse_lyr', 'COMPLETELY_WITHIN', 'Road_lyr')
arcpy.CopyFeature_management('Landuse_lyr', Landuse)
```